# Exoplayer FFmpeg Video Decoder

Tags: ffmpeg, exoplayer, android-ffmpeg

Does any one worked on building FFmpeg Video decoder in Exoplayer? Right now they are supporting Audio Decoder, is there any chance of supporting video decoder also ?